# Is there any way to run a command when building at Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku

I have a python application that needs me to run `python main.py` when building. Is there any way to automatize this proccess, so at the end of every build that command runs? I've seen some articles about heroku.yml, but all of them explain its use in Docker apps, that it's not my case.

Comment: Add the node buildpack on top of your python buildpack and make use of `heroku-postbuild`, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a Procfile :/
Hadn't seen it
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#define-a-procfile